# Select a random patch from an image using matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a gray image of size 400 x 600 . And i want to select **randomly** from this image, a patch of size 50 x 50.

By the way, i tried to write a code for this, and it worked fine. But according to my code below, there is another solution ? In other words, is there another code which can be more sexy than my own code ?

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;

image=imread('my_image.jpg');
image_gray=rgb2gray(image);
[n m]= size(image_gray); % 400 x600

L=50;

x=round(rand(1)*n); % generate a random integer between 1 and 400
y=round(rand(1)*m); % generate a random integer between 1 and 600

%verify if x is > than 400-50 , because if x is equal to 380 for example, so x+50 become %equal to 430, it exceeds the matrix dimension of image...
if(x<=n-L)
a=x:x+(L-1);
else
a=x-(L-1):x;
end

if(y<=m-L)
b=y:y+(L-1);
else
b=y-(L-1):y;
end

crop=image_gray(a,b);
figure(1);
imshow(crop);
```

Comment: you want your code to be more "sexy"??? I have been programing using Matlab for quite a while now and I never encountered a "sexy" code... I strongly suggest you find yourself a "significant other" and spend some time far away from compters and screens.

Comment: desolee , i edited my question

Comment: @Christina Why? It was funnier that way. And now the initial sentence in my answer looks foolish :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is as "sexy" as it gets. Satisfaction guaranteed ;-)

```
% Data
img=imread('my_image.jpg');
image_gray=rgb2gray(img);
[n m]= size(image_gray);
L = 50;

% Crop
crop = image_gray(randi(n-L+1)+(0:L-1),randi(m-L+1)+(0:L-1));
```

If using a Matlab version that doesn't support `randi`, substitute last line by

```
crop = image_gray(ceil(rand*(n-L+1))+(0:L-1),ceil(rand*(m-L+1))+(0:L-1));
```

Comments to your code:

- You shouldn't use `image` as a variable name. It overrides a function.
- You should change `round(rand(1)*n)` to `ceil(rand(1)*n)`. Or use `randi(n)`.
- Instead of `randi(n)`, use `randi(n-L+1)`. That way you avoid the `if`s.

Comment: I just got an error with your code: Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Comment: I'm checking your range values, it doesn't fail every time, but certain index values go out of range.

Comment: Give me a minute, I'll check the values again.

Comment: Hi Luis, I didn't get any more errors from your code, I just gave you +1, nice work.

Comment: @Christina Glad it worked :-) You shouldn't ask people to vote up your question. Voting up or down depends on whether people see your question as showing effort, interesting etc or not

Comment: Sorry but i had a problem with randi , function not found... and when i used ceil , i always obtain the same patch!

Comment: @Christina If you don't have `randi` (old Matlab version), you can use `ceil(rand*(n-L+1))` and `ceil(rand*(m-L+1))`. See updated answer

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling to get this code to work for RGB images, when you compute the size you'll want to add an extra variable for the third dimension. i.e.

```
% Data
img=imread('my_image.jpg');
% Not making anything gray anymore 
[n, m, ~]= size(img);
L = 50;

% Crop - add a : in order to get 3 or more dimensions at the end
crop = img(randi(n-L+1)+(0:L-1),randi(m-L+1)+(0:L-1), :);
```

Super simple but not necessarily obvious at first.